# Remove all related children in Symfony entity ManyToOne

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-one, symfony3.x

That is my relations:

in CategoryField Entity:

```
manyToOne:
    category:
        targetEntity: Category
        inversedBy: fields
        joinColumn:
            name: category_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

in Category:

```
oneToMany:
    fields:
        orderBy: { 'name': 'ASC' }
        targetEntity: CategoryField
        mappedBy: category
        cascade: ['remove']
```

I'm trying to remove all fields when I save category(before inserts new fields):

```
if (!$category = $categoryRepo->find($item_id)) {
    $category = new Category();
} else {
    $category->clearFields();
}
```

That is clear fields method in Category entity:

```
public function clearFields() {
    $this->fields->clear();
}
```

Fields does not remove and new fields inserts in related table. That's makes duplicates.

How can I remove all related records(fields) with my association?